# React Search filter (hooks) through a High Order Component not working

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I try getting my React Search box filter to work.

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-wind-hhphi) what I have so far.

I have a HOC `withSection.js` where I add (for now) just a `<section>` tag to my Components:

```
const withSection = Component => props => (
  <section>
    <Component {...props} />
  </section>
)
```

Then in the parent Component I wrap my SearchBox Component into this HOC and render it:

```
const SectionSearchBox = withSection(SearchBox);

<SectionSearchBox search={search} setSearch={setSearch} />
```

Somehow, as soon I wrap my SearchBox into this HOC, it breaks the functionality?

Whats wrong here?

Comment: please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you sure that something is wrong? I just tried the sandbox, entered one into the input and it filtered the results. Looks good to me.

Comment: @Gh05d I update the question. It has something to do with my High Order Component I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `SectionSearchBox` outside the scope of its parent component. In the codesandbox example it would look something like:

```
import withSection from "./hoc/withSection";
import SearchBox from "./SearchBox";

const SectionSearchBox = withSection(SearchBox);

function ArticlePage() {
  ...
};
```

Otherwise every instance of that component is going to be recreated with each new render of its parent (i.e. when the search term changes). This was causing the search box to appear unfocussed with each key stroke, as a new input element was being put in its place with the value from the previous render.

Comment: thans a lot. So because of the useEffect. That make sense.